# Javascript - How does an object know a function in its class's prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

So..Let's say I have the following code snippet

```
function Rectangle(w,h){
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function(){ return this.width * this.height; }

var object2 = new Rectangle(10,5);
object2.area();
```

So...object2 is invoking area() method, which is defined in Rectangle's prototype.

How does object2 know existence of area() method? I guess there must be something like...pointer in object2 that points to Rectangle's prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implementation specific, but in Firefox and Webkit, the pointer is in the object's `__proto__` property.

See [MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

[Another link](http://dhtmlkitchen.com/learn/js/enumeration/prototype-chain.jsp) that explains in more detail the internals of property lookups.

Comment: // Thank you for your input! Is there a website that I can read about implementation specific?

Comment: // Thank you for the link to MDC !

Comment: // I appreciate your links!! The second one explains a lot.

Comment: @Moon, no worries, you ask interesting questions ;)

Comment: the second link doesn't work anymore. Is there any other good resource explaining how this works?